# How to dynamically change theme based on input color

Tags: typescript, sass, colors

I have a project based on react typescript. I have used .scss files for styling the components. Now I want to change theme based on the color input. Since I have used default colors widely in many components now I don't know how to dynamically change colors apart from inline way .Someone help me out with this.

I was thinking of using styled components where I can define all styles in separate files and importing only those styles in a particular component. And to change color I thought of using 'usestate' and then with useContext send to all components

Comment: How about replacing your colors with CSS variables in your sass/css and then just setting the input color at the root of your document as a variable? Like if you now have `background-color: red`, turn it into `background-color: var(--bg, red)`, and then just set the `--bg` variable to your color somewhere higher up the nodetree.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.